# Upload figure in TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I have a figure like the following. I want to draw it with LaTeX. But I should upload a figure in it. Could you help me with it?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mycirclestyle/.style={draw,fill=blue!30,square, minimum size=1.5cm,inner sep=1pt},
myarrowstyle/.style={stealth-,
    line width=2mm,
    draw=gray!40,}
]


\node[mycirclestyle, name=circle] at (0,0) {\textbf{A conversion}};
\foreach \direction/\angle/\anchordir/\ttext in { south/-90/north/\shortstack{fig1}, west/-180/east/ \shortstack{fig2}}
{\draw[myarrowstyle](circle.\direction)--++(\angle:1cm)node[anchor=\anchordir]{\ttext};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I also could not put the array in two directions[image].

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document, which we can compile as it is. Is showed picture desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you correct result. Just ensure that you have `fig1` & `fig2` in the same directory in which you have this file.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    mycirclestyle/.style={draw,fill=blue!30,minimum size=1.5cm,inner sep=1pt},
    myarrowstyle/.style={stealth-,
        line width=2mm,
        draw=gray!40,}
    ]
    \node[mycirclestyle, name=circle] at (0,0) {\textbf{A conversion}};
    \foreach \direction/\angle/\anchordir/\ttext in {south/-90/north/\shortstack{\includegraphics{fig1}}, west/-180/east/\shortstack{\includegraphics{fig2}}}
    {\draw[myarrowstyle](circle.\direction)--++(\angle:1cm) node[anchor=\anchordir]{\ttext};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```